# Inline-block: why don't two children widths add up to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have two siblings that both have display: inline-block.  Why do I have to lower the sum to 97% to get them to sit next to each other?  Ex:  https://jsfiddle.net/kcscq271/1/

```
  <div class="container">
    <img src="./test.jpg">
    <div class="child1">
      Test Stuff
    </div>
  </div>

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 300px;
}

.child1 {
  display: inline-block;

  width: 80%
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline-block renders html white-space. Put the div right next to the image instead of below.

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="./test.jpg"><div class="child1">
    Test Stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

or try float

```
img {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: You can remove `display: inline-block` when floating.

Answer (score 0):

One other way to achieve this is to write your html like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="./test.jpg"><div class="child1">Test Stuff</div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="./test.jpg"><!--
    --><div class="child1">Test Stuff</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  It seems strange, but not putting whitespace seems to matter.  Also not having a border.